# Is there any way to disable fuzzy search for numbers in text in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have few strings, example:

```
1. 'any text marium malik 127'
2. 'other text marium malik 1.7 other text'
3. 'marium malik 1 7' etc. 
4. 'any other text only'
```

Mapping:

```
'terms' => ['type' => 'text', 'analyzer' => 'new_analyzer']

 'new_analyzer' =>
                     [
                       'tokenizer' => 'standard',
              'filter' => [
                'word_delimiter', 'lowercase', 
               'shingles_2_3',  'remove_space',
                            ]
                        ],
```

If I enable fuzziness and set it to Auto, and I search 'marium malik 127' I get the second and third string as my search result as well, due to fuzziness, although I do not want it. Is there any way to disable fuzziness for numbers?

Complete Mapping:

```
 'body' => [
            'settings' =>
            [

                'analysis' =>
                [                    
                    'analyzer' =>
                    [
                        "extract_number_analyzer" => [
                            "tokenizer" => "standard",
                            "filter" => ["extract_numbers", "decimal_digit"]
                        ],

 'new_analyzer' =>
                        [
                            'tokenizer' => 'standard',
                            'filter' => [
                                'word_delimiter', 'lowercase', 'word_combination', 'length2', 'remove_space',
                            ]
                        ]],
 'filter' =>
                    [
                        'word_combination' => [
                            'type' => 'shingle',
                            'min_shingle_size' => 2,
                            'max_shingle_size' => 3,
                            'output_unigrams' => true
                        ],
                        "extract_numbers" => [
                            "type" => "keep_types",
                            "types" => ["<NUM>"]
                        ],
                        'remove_space' =>
                        [
                            'type' => 'pattern_replace',
                            'pattern' => ' ',
                            'replacement' => ''
                        ],
                        'length2' =>
                        [
                            'type' => 'length',
                            'min' => '3'
                        ]
                    ]
]

  'mappings' =>
            [
                '_doc' =>
                [
 'terms' => ['type' => 'text', 'analyzer' => "new_analyzer", " 
 fields" => ["extracted_number" => ["type" => "text",
                                     "analyzer" => "extract_number_analyzer"
                                ]]]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [keep type token](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keep-types-tokenfilter.html#_settings_example_5) to only keep numerical token in a subfield

exemple of analyzer :

```
PUT /keep_types_example
{
    "settings" : {
        "analysis" : {
            "analyzer" : {
                "extract_number_analyzer" : {
                    "tokenizer" : "standard",
                    "filter" : ["extract_numbers", "decimal_digit"]
                }
            },
            "filter" : {
                "extract_numbers" : {
                    "type" : "keep_types",
                    "types" : [ "<NUM>" ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the mapping

```
...
{
  terms: {
    type: "text",
    analyzer: "new_analyzer",
    fields: {
      extracted_number: {
        type: "text",
        analyzer: "extract_number_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
...
```

Then at query time you can add a clause in your query to match on numerical subfield without fuzziness, then it will match document only if numericals match exactly AND textual content match with fuzziness.

Query example :

```
{
  query: {
    bool: {
      must: [
        {
          match: {
            "terms": {
              "query": "marium malik 127",
              "fuziness": "auto"
            }
          }
        },
        {
           match: {
            "terms.extracted_number": { // or whatever you subfield name is
              "query": "marium malik 127",
              "zero_terms_query": "all" // to match if no extracted number
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! But I am getting error: Mapping definition for [terms] has unsupported parameters: [ fields : {extracted_number={ type=text, analyzer=extract_number_analyzer}}

Comment: the mapping part of my response is only a hint. You should check the documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html

Comment: So, I should add a separate field in my data.json file for number?

Comment: can you post the whole mapping with the "number" sub field ? With the multi field mapping syntax you dont have to add a new property to the document you want to index

Comment: I have added the mapping

Comment: you have a space before "type" attribute name in the subfield, could it be the cause of the error ? (here ---- ["extracted_number" => [" type" => "text", )

Comment: No! It's not the cause. Removed the space and still getting the same error:

Comment: This is brilliant! I ended up making a new `float` field myself with my local parser, but I definitely liked this approach.